# Finding two words anywhere in text with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm not an expert at regular expressions by any stretch of the imagination! I understand the basics of how regex comes together, but through a regular expression, can I search for two words that could appear anywhere within a piece of text?
i.e. the words hot and weather. Could be written as:
the weather was hot
during the hot weather
the weather has become even hotter

Is it possible that a regex can be created to pick up all three scenarios, but not (for example) the picture was shot in poor weather?

Any help would be appreciated - I'm working in PHP5.6 by the way alternative is there a better way to do it that I haven't thought of?

Comment: What do you need? Just know if the words occur, both or just one, or how many times or...

Comment: Hints: word boundaries as `\b`, but regexes don't know the english language, it would assume `hotter` is NOT `hot`.

Comment: Ideally to know if all words occur.  Ideally the regex should be able to accommodate more than two words if necessary.

Comment: @Wrikken: Yes thats a valid point. I was thinking of adding a . character, but then that would also match hotel which wouldn't work. :(

Comment: Yep, parsing the _meaning_ of text is waaaaay out of scope here. You'll need whole dictionaries, semantic rules, syntactic rules, a team of star programmers, and a few years if that's what you want. Or live with the occasional over-matching (hotel, shot) or undermatching (not matching hotter), whichever of those 2 suits your case the most.

Comment: @Wrikken: Yes agreed! Definitely go with the under matching!

Comment: You could expand it out to something like this: `(\bweather\b.*hot(ter|test)?\b|\bhot(ter|test)?\b.*weather\b)`

Comment: @KyleWalker: indeed, I assumed the words would be supplied by an end-user which does not know regexes. If that assumption is wrong and these words can be entered by regex-savvy developers, then that would work indeed. Don't forget the `\b` before the first 'hot' & last 'weather' though ;).

Comment: In that case you could have the user enter two words and simply append some common endings to words to help it catch a bit more, narrowing down some false positives, but also adding some false negatives. Oh correct need 2 more `\b`'s

Comment: @KyleWalker: Thanks for your comments, could you expand out on what you mean with that - possibly as a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need those two words you could have the regex search with an optional list of word endings.

For Example:
`(\bweather\b.*hot(ter|test)?\b|\bhot(ter|test)?\b.*\bweather\b)`

But if you need to build the regex from a user's input you would want to have a full list of possible endings:
`(s|er|est|ier|iest|ter|test|etc|etc)?`

Example:
`(\bweather(s|er|est|ier|iest|ter|test|etc|etc)?\b.*hot(s|er|est|ier|iest|ter|test|etc|etc)?\b|\b(s|er|est|ier|iest|ter|test|etc|etc)?\b.*\bweather(s|er|est|ier|iest|ter|test|etc|etc)?\b)`

The only problem is it would miss endings like `silly` being `silliest` or `see` being `saw` without adding additional logic to look at the original words.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I'll give that a try and let you know how I get on!